# EDIT: Portable Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, console

I have built my project and ran the .exe on a computer without Visual Studio. It wouldn't run.

I have searched up how to build my project with all the .dll but only got how to turn .dll into .exe, I am looking to be able to use my build on a computer/laptop without visual studio, which is what I think has the .dll to run it.

Can anyone please share a link or tutorial on how to do this?

I am using C# Console .NET Core 3.1.

EDIT: For anyone wanting to make their program portable check the answer below

Comment: On the computer where your application does not run, look into the Windows Event Viewer for errors logged while trying to run your application. These errors will give you details on what the problem is.

Comment: The question is too broad to be answered on Stackoverflow. If you want to get an answer, provide a more detailed question

Comment: What other information should I provide?

Comment: "*It wouldn't run" - is not a suitable way to ask a question. You need to learn standard windows debugging techniques like you using event viewer. I would suggest you ask a senior developer in your organization to help you with this task as working you through this will likely be beyond the scope of a simple Q and A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all, when you want your code to run in another machine, make sure that either

- the other machine has .Net installed or
- you made a portable version of your app

Take for instance [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxpiR.png) simple ConsoleApp.

You can just build by clicking `F6`, but when it runs, it look for the .NET libraries, which are on your PC only, since you installed Visual Studio.

So, if you want to run it on another PC, you have to publish it. For this, you can, by double-clicking the .sln file (which opens VS) then opening the solution explorer tab, right-click the one project (not the .cs file only) you want to build, click publish > target a folder > set specific target to ClickOnce > go hitting next till the configuration tab. In that, select the deployment mode as self-contained, so, all necessary libraries will be in the .exe file. Finnaly, on file publish options, select Produce single file, so everythong will be on the .exe file. Then clicks publish and you should see the "published" app on the selected folder.

Hope I helped!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxpiR.png): [Visual Studio with simple console app open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxpiR.png)